# Balance in wallet not updated after mint

Tags: openzeppelin, balances, mint

on my test token using OZ ERC20 I can mint successfully and the tokens show in the wallet. this is the relevant code

```
    contract TestToken is ERC20, Pausable, AccessControlEnumerable  {
        bytes32 public constant PAUSER_ROLE = keccak256("PAUSER_ROLE");
        bytes32 public constant MINTER_ROLE = keccak256("MINTER_ROLE");
    
        constructor() ERC20("MyToken", "MTK") {
            _grantRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, msg.sender);
            _grantRole(PAUSER_ROLE, msg.sender);
           // _mint(msg.sender, 100 * 10 ** decimals());
            _grantRole(MINTER_ROLE, msg.sender);
        }
//I use this function to mint successfully
   function mint(address to, uint256 amount) public onlyRole(MINTER_ROLE) {
        _mint(to, amount * 10 ** decimals());
    }
```

my other token - I use safemoon clone and want to add OZ access control and make it mintable.

```
contract SFMOZToken is Context, ERC20, Ownable, Pausable, AccessControl {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    using Address for address;

    bytes32 public constant PAUSER_ROLE = keccak256("PAUSER_ROLE");
    bytes32 public constant MINTER_ROLE = keccak256("MINTER_ROLE");

    mapping (address => uint256) private _rOwned;
    mapping (address => uint256) private _tOwned;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) private _allowances;

    mapping (address => bool) private _isExcludedFromFee;

    mapping (address => bool) private _isExcluded;
    address[] private _excluded;
   
    uint256 private constant MAX = ~uint256(0);
    uint256 private _tTotal = 400 * 10**6 * 10**9;
    uint256 private _rTotal = (MAX - (MAX % _tTotal));
    uint256 private _tFeeTotal;

    string private _name = "oztoken";
    string private _symbol = "FCKN";
    uint8 private _decimals = 9;

//omit irrelevant code
 constructor () ERC20("SFMOZToken", "FKN") {
        _grantRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, msg.sender);
        _grantRole(PAUSER_ROLE, msg.sender);
        _grantRole(MINTER_ROLE, msg.sender);

        _rOwned[_msgSender()] = _rTotal;
        
        IUniswapV2Router02 _uniswapV2Router = IUniswapV2Router02(0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D);//UniswapV2Router02 deployed on Ropsten
         // Create a uniswap pair for this new token
        uniswapV2Pair = IUniswapV2Factory(_uniswapV2Router.factory())
            .createPair(address(this), _uniswapV2Router.WETH());

        // set the rest of the contract variables
        uniswapV2Router = _uniswapV2Router;
        
        //exclude owner and this contract from fee
        _isExcludedFromFee[owner()] = true;
        _isExcludedFromFee[address(this)] = true;
        
         emit Transfer(address(0), _msgSender(), _tTotal);
    }


 function MyMint(address to,uint256 amount) public onlyRole(MINTER_ROLE) {
        _mint(to, amount * 10 ** decimals());
      
    }
```

when i deploy SFMOZToken the initial amount is added in my wallet. but then when I call the MyMint() function the transaction is ok and I can see the total supply in etherscan is increasing https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x486bad26dbcde6db2098782964e43c79f0ca60f5456958663e57870d2bea7e9d but the balance in my wallet is not changing.

Comment: is this the address of your wallet 0xd66e8c77bb3d5d44294c8a3d8c68658ebe41dc36?

Comment: yes this is the address

Comment: How are you checking your balance?? because this tx tell you that token are transferred to this address 0xd66e8c77bb3d5d44294c8a3d8c68658ebe41dc36

Comment: in my metamask the amount stays the same

Comment: remove and add the token again in metamask. the contract address is probably 0x56216c7cd96cf7b44bdbc0af4f5ea83227310745

Comment: Hii I am facing just the opposite of this. After minting, my metamask balance gets updated but the holder's section in etherscan remains the same. Even the balanceOf function gives the updated balance.